# Access Services-Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, access-services

Can we reuse MS Access Forms 2010 in SharePoint 2010. I am sure, SharePoint cannot handle that.

My understanding of Sharepoint is, We can use Access Services in SharePoint , to migrate data to and from Access database.

Am I missing something in here?

Thanks

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-integrating-data-between-access-and-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131463.aspx <-- this link seems to imply that you can, but it doesn't explain how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

With access service, you can publish your MS Access Database to Sharepoint.

read this technet will guide about the new stuff;
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748640(v=office.14).aspx

Here is very strater blog wil guide you the steps.
http://4sysops.com/archives/access-services-in-sharepoint-server-2010/

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be better if you could provide the relevant information in the links in case the urls change.